# How to bring local ~/.ssh/config into scope for my Docker/Docksal CLI?

Tags: docker, docksal

I use domain aliases in local make files that are defined in my ~/.ssh/config file. These work at my OSX CLI, but flunk in my Docker/Docksal environments. My private SSH keys are working, its the configs for my domain aliases that are the problem.

I would like the use the domain alias for my repo from within the CLI of my Docker/Docksal instances.

My project make files use this alias - which works perfectly (from my ~/.ssh/config):

```
Host myrepo
    User git
    Port 22
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

So from the 'make' file I am using - works as expected from local CLI, does not work from the Docker/Docksal instance CLI environment:

```
projects[my_cool_module][download][url] = "myrepo:my_org/my_cool_module"
```

So my question - how do I configure Docksal's SSH Agent to see my local ~/.ssh/config?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to bring this to your container. Each container is like a VM to your host. You can always copy this file over to your `cli` container though. But that would a manual task done per project.